# Uninstalling MS sql server 2012 issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to uninstall ms sql server 2012. But when I click **Microsoft SQL Server 2012(64 bit)** and choose remove option it shows like this.
[image]

Then how can I remove the MS SQL Server 2012? Please help.

Comment: Please see workaround posted by Microsoft team in this thread https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/974626/cannot-uninstall-sql-express-2014-on-windows-7-sp1

Comment: Also see https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition